# UnmarshalException when doing unmarshling of xml

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Exception javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://services.forddirect.fordvehicles.com/searchTest", local:"ClassName"). Expected elements are (none)

I am pasting the code part by which I am doing unmarshling of xml

```
try {

        File file = new File("ReflectionInput.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(SearchTest.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        SearchTest className = (SearchTest) jaxbUnmarshaller
                .unmarshal(file);
        System.out.println(className);

    } catch(JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

getting exception when unmarshalling from xml.

```
Exception javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://services.forddirect.fordvehicles.com/searchTest", local:"ClassName"). Expected elements are (none)
 at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:647)
 at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:258)
 at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:253)
 at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:120)
 at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1052)
 at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:483)
 at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:464)
 at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:152)
 at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
```

xsd file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <xs:schema xmlns="http://services.forddirect.fordvehicles.com/searchTest"
  attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
  targetNamespace="http://services.forddirect.fordvehicles.com/searchTest"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="SearchTest" type="searchTest">
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="searchTest">
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="ClassName" type="className" minOccurs="0"
     maxOccurs="unbounded" />
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="className">
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="param" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"
     maxOccurs="unbounded" />
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType> 
 </xs:schema>
```

xml file

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <ClassName xmlns="http://services.forddirect.fordvehicles.com/searchTest">
     <param name ="make">Ford</param>
       <param name ="model">Mustang</param>
       <param name ="year">2011</param>
       <param name ="dealerPACode">2011</param>
       <param name ="segment">car</param>
       <param name ="segmentdefiner">NGP_ModelInfo_VehicleType</param>
       <param name           ="configtoken">Config[|Ford|Mustang|2014|1|1.|100A.P8A.....COU.~YZKAA.V6.LESS.]</param>
  <param name ="vin">3FA6P0H79DR338449</param>
     </ClassName>
```

Comment: Is this the complete XML? Why is 'ClassName' not closed?

Answer (score 0):

### What the Problem is:

Because `SearchTest` is a global element with a named complex type, an `@XmlRootElement` annotation is not generated for the `SearchTest` class.  Instead an `@XmlElementDecl` annotation is generated for it on the `ObjectFactory` class.  This is because in JAXB classes correspond to complex types, and named complex types may have more that one global element that corresponds to it.

```
  <xs:element name="SearchTest" type="searchTest">
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="searchTest">
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="ClassName" type="className" minOccurs="0"
     maxOccurs="unbounded" />
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

### How to Fix it:

When creating a `JAXBContext` on a model generated from an XML Schema, you should create it on the `ObjectFactory` class or the package name of the generated model instead of an individual model class to get all the necessary metadata.

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
```

### For More Information

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html